# React render Table with two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i am trying to Render a Table dynamically based on a JSON File. The header of the Table is working as expected but i don't know how i could achieve to render the Body based on the Layout which is defined in the JSON File and then use the Data i got using an API call.

This is how my JSON File looks like:

```
{
  "Header": [
    {
      "Column": "Id"
    },
    {
      "Column": "Account Name"
    },
    {
      "Column": "City"
    },
    {
      "Column": "Street"
    },
    {
      "Column": "Created Date"
    },
    {
      "Column": "Industry"
    }
  ],
  "Body": [
    {
      "Body": "id"
    },
    {
      "Body": "accountName"
    },
    {
      "Body": "city"
    },
    {
      "Body": "street"
    },
    {
      "Body": "createdDate"
    },
    {
      "Body": "industry"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here i am fetching the Data as well as the JSON:

```
    const [header, setHeader] = useState([]);
    const [body, setBody] = useState([]);
    const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/files/Account/AccountList")
            .then(response => {
                setHeader(response.data.Header);
                setBody(response.data.Body);
            })
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/${object}`)
            .then(response => {
                setRecords(response.data);
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

And this is how i render the Table:

```
            <table className="Object-List--Table">
                <thead>
                <tr className="Object-List--Table-Header">
                    {header.map((head) => {
                        return (
                            <th className="Header-Column">{head.Column}</th>
                        );
                    })}
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {records.map((record) => {
                    return (
                        <tr className="Object-List--Table--Body" key={record.id}>
                            <td className="Body-Column">
                                <Link to={`/${object}/${record.id}`}>{record.id}</Link>
                            </td>
                            <td className="Body-Column">{record.accountName}</td>
                            <td className="Body-Column">{record.city}</td>
                            <td className="Body-Column">{record.street}</td>
                            <td className="Body-Column">{record.createdDate}</td>
                            <td className="Body-Column">{record.industry}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is the Response i get when calling the API

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "accountName": "Rainer Zufall",
        "city": "Dortmund",
        "street": "Teststraße 42",
        "createdDate": "2021-01-03T23:00:00.000+00:00",
        "industry": "Developer"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "accountName": "7z226b46",
        "city": "ngw4125",
        "street": "t3rxjo4v 34",
        "createdDate": "2020-01-06T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "industry": "Developer"
    }
]
```

My question is now, how i could achieve to render the Body of the Table based on the Records i am getting through the API as well as through the Body which is defined in the JSON File.

I would like to have the Body of the table like this:

```
<td className="Body-Column">{record[body].Body}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried how to do this and i found a Solution for my Problem. If anyone else has something like this, this is the Code i am using for the Moment:

```
{records.map((record, index) => {
    return (
        <tr className="Object-List--Table--Body" key={`Row-${index}`}>
            {
                body.map((row, index) => {
                    return (
                        <td
                            className="Body-Column"
                            key={`Cell-${index}`}>{record[row.Body]}</td>
                    );
                })
            }
        </tr>
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls use below code for tbody map.

```
records.Body.map( record => {
<tr>
   <td className="Body-Column">{record.Body}</td>
   ...
</tr>
});

records.map((record) => {
    return (
        <tr className="Object-List--Table--Body" key={record.id}>
            <td className="Body-Column">{record.accountName}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
    );
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but when i try your code, i get the following Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Just a reminder: The record doesn't have a Body, the body is in the JSON File. The Response of the API looks like this:
-accountName: "Rainer Zufall"
-city: "Dortmund"
-createdDate: "2021-01-03T23:00:00.000+00:00"
-id: 1
-industry: "Developer"
-street: "Teststraße 42"

Comment: Can you please provide the exact json response you are trying with by editing the question?

Comment: You may have two different loop for the different kind of data as i updated my answer

Comment: I don't really understand how this should work when i have to Arrays and want to render the Records Array based on the content of the Body.